# Changing Date and time Time formate from Json Response

Tags: android, json, date, date-format

How to parse the date from json response and set in textview.

My Json Response :

> {"createdate":"2016-03-14 04:00:01"}

What I want in my Textview:

> 4:00PM 03/14

my listview adapter :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context ctx;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    TextView tvPlaceName, tvTime;
    String longitude, latitude;

    String out;

    ListViewAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {

        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.arraylist = arraylist;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arraylist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

        tvPlaceName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlaceName);
        tvTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);



        //  Log.d("uname", arraylist.get(position).get("Username"));
        tvPlaceName.setText(arraylist.get(position).get("alert_message"));
         tvTime.setText(arraylist.get(position).get("createdate"));


        longitude = arraylist.get(position).get("longitude");
        latitude = arraylist.get(position).get("latitude");


        return itemView;
    }



    private String convertTime(String time) {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa MM-dd");
        java.util.Date date = null;

        try {
            date = format.parse(time);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String convertedDate = format1.format(date);

        return convertedDate;
    }

}
```

I have fetched my response, but I don't know how to formate date in a particular way.

Suggestions are heartily welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Date String to Some Java Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854780/parse-date-string-to-some-java-object)

Comment: check my edited question.. how to format date time and set in textview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this

```
tvTime.setText(convertTime(arraylist.get(position).get("createdate")));
```

Use the following code

```
 private String convertTime(String time) {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa MM-dd");
        java.util.Date date = null;

        try {
            date = format.parse(time);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String convertedDate = format1.format(date);

        return convertedDate;
    }
```

Comment: i am having listview.. i am able to fetch response.. but how to set that in my textview ?

Comment: Just add above function in your adapter...and while setting name to text use this function

Comment: else show me how you are setting name to textview so that I will tell you how to use above function for it.

Comment: tvTime.setText(arraylist.get(position).get("createdate"));

Comment: createdate is name of date time response

Comment: check my update quesiotn. i have put code.. can u show me now

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code

Below Code returns calendar object

```
public static Calendar StringDateConverter(String date) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    try {
        return dateToCalendar(df.parse(date.toUpperCase()));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static Calendar dateToCalendar(Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return calendar;
    }
```

use this code to convert calendar event to string

```
public static String ConvertDateToDate(Calendar calendar) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mmaa MM/dd", Locale.getDefault());
    return df.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Comment: i am having listview.. i am able to fetch response.. but how to set that in my textview ?

Answer (score 2):

```
public String convertDateFormat() {
        String formatedDate ="";
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mmaa MM/dd");

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = inputFormat.parse(parseJsonAndGetCreateDateString());            
            formatedDate = outputFormat.format(date);

        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return formatedDate;
    }

public String parseJsonAndGetCreateDateString(){
String response = "{\"createdate\":\"2016-03-14 04:00:01\"}";
String createDate = "";
try{

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
createDate = obj.getString("createdate");

}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
return createDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private String getFormate(String date) throws ParseException {
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date);
    Log.d("Date", String.valueOf(d));
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(d);
    String monthName = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mmaa MM/yyyy").format(cal.getTime());
    return monthName;
}
```

and use this to get your format

```
        try {
            String myFormate = getFormate(d);
            Log.d("date", myFormate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here **d** is `String d = "2016-03-14 04:00:01";`

Answer (score 1):

try This:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a MM/dd");
SimpleDateFormat hh_mm_ss = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

 try {
     Date dat1 =hh_mm_ss.parse(arraylist.get(position).get("createdate"));
                    String out = dateFormat2.format(dat1);
                   tvTime.setText(out);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

It will convert your date format and give you an output like "time 04:00:01 AM 03/14"

Comment: i am having listview.. i am able to fetch response.. but how to set that in my textview ?

Comment: well if you are using recyclerview you can do something like this   holder.tv_neme.setText(out);

Comment: @tiger : This is exactley as u want it

Answer (score 1):

exact your result

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma MM/dd");
            SimpleDateFormat hh_mm_ss = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

             try {
                                Date dat1 = hh_mm_ss.parse("2016-03-14 04:00:01");
                                String out = dateFormat2.format(dat1);
                                System.out.println(out);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```