# Missing Month and Day In Java SimpleDateFormat parse

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Using SimpleDateFormat:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-YYYY kk:mm:ss.SSS");
Date extractedDate = df.parse(possibleDate);
```

Input given:

```
11-May-2017 21:45:33.614
```

Output data object:

```
Sun Jan 01 21:45:33 MST 2017
```

I have tried lots of iterations but it won't pull the month and day.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854780/parse-date-string-to-some-java-object

Answer (score 4):

**Use `dd-MMM-yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS` as pattern**

Example :

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS");
Date extractedDate = df.parse("11-May-2017 21:45:33.614");
System.out.println(extractedDate);
```

Output :

```
Thu May 11 21:45:33 BDT 2017
```

Another thing If you use `kk` for hour, hour should be represent between 1 to 24. If the hour between 0 to 23 use `HH` instead of `kk`

Comment: perfect thanks, I was about to start iterating again on different combinations