# Compare the month / year of a string

Tags: java, datetime

I am using an if statement to do a set of commands when an INT (which in this case is a number of a month like 02) is equal  to a STRING (which is a date fully written out like so --> 02/14/1998) the fully written out dates are in a file

So I am asking the user to type in a date and a month (INTS) and compare that to the fully written out dates in the file and when the month is the month of the fully written out date and same w/ the year do a set of calculations.

```
    int userTypedMonth, userTypedYear
    string fileDate 
    if(userTypedMonth == fileDate && userTypedYear == fileDate){
          5+5=10
    }
```

I know this is the wrong syntax of code but i wanted to show how Im trying to explain it.

Comment: Is it a homework? You can try to take a look at java.util.LocalDate library: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: You can turn the int to a String, but you definitely should not use `==` for strings

Comment: Yeah, you must parse the date string. Then you can get the month and year integers to compare

Comment: @cricket_007 anyway you could show me how to do that? I would really appreciate it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854780/parse-date-string-to-some-java-object

Comment: Once you have some date like object, then use something like getMonth and getYear

Comment: @cricket_007 im trying and im still messing something up. Im pretty sure my parse syntax is wrong.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include the code you have

Answer (score 0):

You can `fileDate.split("/")` to split the fileDate into a String[] where index 0 is the month ("02"), index 1 is the day ("14"), and index 2 is the ("1998"). Then you could compare using `userTypedMonth.equals(fileDateArray[0])` and `userTypedYear.equals(fileDateArray[2])`, assuming the userTypedMonth/Year were Strings instead of ints. If they are ints, use `String.valueOf(userTypedMonth/Year)` to compare.