# How to convert timestamp to 13 digit decimal in JAVA

Tags: java, timestamp, decimal

Is there some function in Java, for parsing timestamp to decimal?

**Input**:  2023-07-04 00:00:00.0

**Expected** **output**: 1687771449497

Comment: 2023-07-04 00:00:00.0 is certainly not 1687771449497ms since epoch.

Comment: its just an example, not right conversion..

Comment: Refer parsing - https://stackoverflow.com/q/8854780/11566161 and converting - https://stackoverflow.com/q/11871120/11566161

Comment: I think we don't have a single direct method() to do this.

Comment: "it is just an example" - then we need to know what the "decimal" is expected to be representing (milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z is one standard, but can we assume that without having a valid example?) || also what type is the input (`String`, `Timestamp`, ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `LocalDateTime` for you timestamp representation in Java code, so you can you the following approach to convert timestamp into epoch millis:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2023, 7, 4, 0, 0);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.systemDefault());
long millis = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```